# Refresh current page after submit GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

i created a UI with google apps script , i need to reload the page after that i click submit , my UI must take the initial state..
I have my function doGet(), there i create my form and my panels , and i have function OnSumbit there i submit my form in the spreadsheet, via a button. 
The idea is when i click on the button he must submit in the spreadsheet 
How can i do this?? thank you for helping.

```
function onSubmit(e){
sheet.getRange("M"+lastRow).setValue(nbPage);
sheet.getRange("B"+lastRow).setValue(Folder);
sheet.getRange("C"+lastRow).setValue(clients);
sheet.getRange("D"+lastRow).setValue(project_Title);
sheet.getRange("E"+lastRow).setValue(Language_name);
sheet.getRange("T"+lastRow).setValue(platform_details);
sheet.getRange("M"+lastRow).setValue(nbPage);
sheet.getRange("G"+lastRow).setValue(Process_name);
sheet.getRange("I"+lastRow).setValue(Project_status); 
sheet.getRange("J"+lastRow).setValue(Process_status);
sheet.getRange("K"+lastRow).setValue(stage_name);
sheet.getRange("O"+lastRow).setValue(dueDate);
sheet.getRange("N"+lastRow).setValue(date_rcv);
sheet.getRange("H"+lastRow).setValue(Artwork);
sheet.getRange("L"+lastRow).setValue(batchNb+1);
sheet.getRange("S"+lastRow).setValue(Remarks);
sheet.getRange("P"+lastRow).setValue(dateTimeIndia);
//Reload page 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to end the onSubmit() with the function that calls the Ui.  You state it is doGet(), so would look like this.

```
function onSubmit(e){
sheet.getRange("M"+lastRow).setValue(nbPage);
sheet.getRange("B"+lastRow).setValue(Folder);
sheet.getRange("C"+lastRow).setValue(clients);
sheet.getRange("D"+lastRow).setValue(project_Title);
sheet.getRange("E"+lastRow).setValue(Language_name);
sheet.getRange("T"+lastRow).setValue(platform_details);
sheet.getRange("M"+lastRow).setValue(nbPage);
sheet.getRange("G"+lastRow).setValue(Process_name);
sheet.getRange("I"+lastRow).setValue(Project_status); 
sheet.getRange("J"+lastRow).setValue(Process_status);
sheet.getRange("K"+lastRow).setValue(stage_name);
sheet.getRange("O"+lastRow).setValue(dueDate);
sheet.getRange("N"+lastRow).setValue(date_rcv);
sheet.getRange("H"+lastRow).setValue(Artwork);
sheet.getRange("L"+lastRow).setValue(batchNb+1);
sheet.getRange("S"+lastRow).setValue(Remarks);
sheet.getRange("P"+lastRow).setValue(dateTimeIndia);

doGet();
}
```